# Processing.py blank window issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, 2d, processing

I tried writing an A* alg using processing.py but I am having an issue with the beginning of the code: my window is totally blank

So, I want a grid to appear waiting for the user to click on a cell and then to fill that cell with a black rectangle.
But, I only want this to run at the beginning of my code so I didn't put it in the draw function.

Here is my code:

```
taille = 400
pas = taille // 20

def setup():
    size(taille, taille)
    background(255, 255, 255)
    stroke(0)
    strokeWeight(2)
    frameRate(20)
    for i in range(pas, taille, pas):
        line(i, 0, i, taille)
        line(0, i, taille, i)
    drawRect()

def drawRect():    
    x, y = pressed()
    for i in range(1, taille // pas - 1):
        for j in range(1, taille // pas - 1):
            if i * pas <= x and x <= (i + 1) * pas:
                if j * pas <= y and y <= (j + 1) * pas:
                    rect(i * pas, j * pas, pas, pas)

def pressed():
    while True:
        if mousePressed:
            return (mouseX, mouseY)
```

I highly suspect that the error is coming from the drawRect function since I managed to display the grid before adding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, I want a grid to appear waiting for the user to click on a cell and then to fill that cell with a black rectangle. But, I only want this to run at the beginning of my code so I didn't put it in the draw function.

Anyway I recommend to use a `draw` function, to continuously draw the scene dependent on the current states of your program.

Note, your program hangs in an endless loop. The variables `mousePressed`, `mouseX` and `mouseY` are never updated. This variables don't change their state magically. They change their state between 2 frames, after the `draw` function has been executed *Processing* does the event handling and changes the built in variables. You don't give *Processing* any chance to do this job.

Create to variables, which notice the x and y window coordinate of the "click":

```
enter_x = -1
enter_y = -1
```

Implement the `mousePressed` event to receive the "click":

```
def mousePressed():
global enter_x, enter_y
if enter_x < 0 or enter_y < 0:
    enter_x = mouseX
    enter_y = mouseY
```

Draw the black rectangle to the if the "click" coordinates are valid (`>= 0`) in the `draw function`:

```
def draw():   
    global enter_x, enter_y

    if enter_x >= 0 and enter_y >= 0:
        stroke(0)  
        fill(0)
        ix = enter_x // pas
        iy = enter_y // pas
        rect(ix * pas, iy * pas, pas, pas)
```

The full code may look like this:

```
taille = 400
pas = taille // 20

def setup():
    size(taille, taille)
    background(255, 255, 255)
    stroke(0)
    strokeWeight(2)
    frameRate(20)
    for i in range(pas, taille, pas):
        line(i, 0, i, taille) 
        line(0, i, taille, i)

enter_x = -1
enter_y = -1

def mousePressed():
    global enter_x, enter_y
    if enter_x < 0 or enter_y < 0:
        enter_x = mouseX
        enter_y = mouseY    

def draw():   
    global enter_x, enter_y

    if enter_x >= 0 and enter_y >= 0:
        stroke(0)  
        fill(0)
        ix = enter_x // pas
        iy = enter_y // pas
        rect(ix * pas, iy * pas, pas, pas)
```

Note, it may be necessary to draw the grid in the `draw` function too. In general it is better to redraw the scene every frame, than "undoing" something what has been draw.